# How to fix materialvideoloadeddata event not being fired

Tags: aframe

I am working on a framework for a 360 tour and creating some popups that auto size planes to fit their textures. As a result, I'm looking to add an event listener to a plane to see when its material texture loads or a video loads for it and resize to the texture's dimensions. I have the images working for the most part (asset loading is causing some issues, but I have some ideas for that), but videos are not working.

My normal event listener for 'materialtextureloaded' doesn't fire off for videos so I tried using the 'materialvideoloadeddata' but that doesn't seem to be working either. Neither of these event listeners fires when the video asset is used as a texture, but the texture loaded fires when an image is used.

```
el.addEventListener('materialvideoloadeddata', function(){console.log("videodataloaded");});
el.addEventListener('materialtextureloaded', function(){console.log("materialtextureloaded");});
```

Additional note, the 'materialtextureloaded' event fires when I set a material's source via a url and not using the asset loading system. All of the videos are loaded into the asset system, though and I would like to load them from there.

Fires off the 'materialvideoloadeddata':

```
videoPlayer.setAttribute("material", "src: assets/video/myvideo.mp4');
```

Does not fire off the 'materialvideoloadeddata':

```
videoPlayer.setAttribute("material", "src: #' + myvideoId);
```

I would expect that the asset loading would fire this event as well, but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Try listen to the actually `<video>` element's `loadeddata` event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadeddata_event

If using selector, you have the `<video>` already.

If using URL, video can be obtained via `this.el.getObject3D('mesh').material.map.image`.